# Magento 2.2.3: Create order in backend, add product had discount rule showing incorrect

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, magento2.2.3

I had some bug in backend magento 2.2.3 
**Steps to reproduce**
1.Create a discount rule based on attribute set which have configurable products
2. Save & Apply rule
3.Run command reindex to apply catalog price rules
4.Open Backend Magento 2 : Go to Customers -> All customers -> Choosen one customer 
5. Click Manage Shoping Cart -> Selected product has discount rule -> Click " Add selections to my cart " .
**Expected result**
Product has been added showing correct price with discount rule like in frontend. ( Discount 30% )
[image]

But in backend, price product showing incorrect 
 
[image]

Backend :I tried to click " Update Items and Quantities" in backend, but product had price rule not updated price.
In Frotend 
Price of product showing incorrect, but subtotal show correct price when product had discount rule. 
[image]

I tried to reproduce in Magento 2.3. No error to show,price had discount rule showing correct , pls let's me some my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I checked in Magento2.2.3. And it's working properly. Please do it again and check it.

Comment: Hi @DhadukMitesh, Thanks you. I saw this, maybe error just only showing in Magento 2.2.3 EE

Answer (score 0):

just updated my code to fix to my bug 
 . I don't know why getFinalPrice ignore catalog price rules. but i fixed it. 
 
Add event:

```
<event name="catalog_product_get_final_price">
    <observer name="catalogrule" instance="Magento\CatalogRule\Observer\ProcessFrontFinalPriceObserver" />
</event>
```

And cache clean , cache flush. Good luck!